# Android Koin DI - ViewModel injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

Did anybody solved injecting ViewModel with Koin ?

I am using

```
    def koin_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
    // Testing
    androidTestImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version"
```

And I am trying to inject ViewModel via Koin.

I have an empty ViewModel:

```
class AuthViewModel
constructor(
    val authRepository: AuthRepository
) : ViewModel()
{


}
```

And my koin module looks like this:

```
val authModule = module {
    viewModel { AuthViewModel(get()) }
}
```

But keyword viewModel in the authModule is not recognized, nor there is a Koin import for it.

I have tried manually to import:

```
import org.koin.android.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel
import org.koin.java.architecture.ext.viewModel
```

But these imports are also not recognized.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for that I think you will need

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
```

in my playground project I have it configured like this:

```
implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1'
implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:2.0.1'
implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.0.1'
```

Comment: Thanks, I could not find these implementations anywhere. With this, works everything.

Answer (score 4):

They merged a lot of module together in *3.1.0* for instance all you would need is :

```
implementation 'io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.4.0'
```

Comment: i have a new project, solution was fine !